# Load conted on an ASPX page using web usercontrols or loading HTML via Jquery $.get

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance, webusercontrol

I have a rather large ASPX application which has a number of web user controls on the primary page.  Over the last several months i have migrated all of the server side functionality in the web user controls to AJAX and client-side scripting.  Currently, i have web user controls which are displaying just HTML content because i would like to keep the complexity of the main page limited as well as modular.

Is it better to convert the existing web user controls to simply HTML files and load them using $.get or will i be negatively impacting performance?  Are there any disadvantages to changing the web user controls over to HTML and loading via jquery?

Comment: What do you mean with changing web user controls to HTML? The output normally is HTML and you can do a `$.get()` on these controls.

Comment: Ok, i was not aware i could load an ascx file via jquery.  I had the controls registered on the main page, but if i can simply reference them via url and load them, then i guess its the same either way.